# How to build solr.tgz file from source using "ant package"

Tags: ant, solr, solr4, solrcloud

I want to build a .tgz distribution file from solr.

The build.xml file tells me to use "ant package".

However, running ant package gets everything from svn and builds ./package/solr-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip whereas my code base is from lucene_4_10_x branch.

How do I build ./package/solr-4.10.3.zip from the source code?

I need to build from the source code because I have some local changes that I want to compile and deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [LUCENE-4288](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4288), Solr will only package properly if it's checked out from SVN by default. However, if you change `package-src-tgz` to `package-local-src-tgz`, it will properly package. Find the following lines in `solr/build.xml`:

```xml
<!-- make a distribution -->
<target name="package" depends="package-src-tgz,..."/>
```

And change `package-src-tgz` to `package-local-src-tgz`.

```xml
<!-- make a distribution -->
<target name="package" depends="package-local-src-tgz,..."/>
```

Then just rerun `ant package` inside `solr/`, and the packaged archives (`solr-<version>-SNAPSHOT.tgz` and `solr-<version>-SNAPSHOT.zip`) will be available under `solr/package/`.